# Python App created with PyInstaller has a slow startup

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have an application written in Python that uses PyQt and Flask for the GUI framework.

Running the application has a loading time of 10 seconds, but after compiling it with Pyinstaller it takes over 10 minutes to open.
Previous versions of the executable used to worked fine, so I went back to previous tool versions in case the delay was due to the updates but still taking a long time.

I am compiling it using --onedir --console. If I include the --debug "all" tag the programm loads fast again.